# Need to do Index/Match within ElseIf statement parameters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I started learning VBA roughly a month ago and I've finally ran across a problem I can't find an answer to on Stack. I'm working on a large automated analysis I can run on my Amazon advertising campaigns to tell me whether to up bid, down bid, or pause. Since there are so many scenarios my If statements have a lot of "And/Or" built into them. I'm now on a scenario where I cannot call out a specific range or cell, but need the if statement to only work when a value an unknown number of spaces away is greater than a static cell. Here is my current code for this portion of the analysis

```
Sub FutureAnalysis()

Dim Spend As Variant, Sales As Variant, ACoS As Variant
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Spend = ActiveCell(x + 5, 0)
Sales = ActiveCell(x + 6, 0)

For x = 7 To FinalRow
    If (Cells(x, 1).Value = "Sum of CPC Bid" Or Cells(x, 1).Value = "Sum of Bid") Then
        If IsError(Spend) Or IsError(Sales) Then
            ActiveCell(x, 1) = "Whoops"
        ElseIf ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value > 1 And ActiveCell(x + 6, 0).Value > 1 Then
            ActiveCell(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=AVERAGE(INDEX(RC2:RC[-1],MATCH(R5C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-1],0)):INDEX(RC2:RC[-1],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-1],0)))*R6C"
            ActiveCell(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=AVERAGE(INDEX(RC2:RC[-2],MATCH(R5C[-2],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)):INDEX(RC2:RC[-2],MATCH(R6C[-2],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)))*R6C"
            ActiveCell(x, 3).FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=AVERAGE(INDEX(RC2:RC[-3],MATCH(R5C[-3],R7C2:R7C[-3],0)):INDEX(RC2:RC[-3],MATCH(R6C[-3],R7C2:R7C[-3],0)))*R6C"

        ElseIf ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value = 0 And ActiveCell(x + 6, 0).Value = 0 Then
            ActiveCell(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=INDEX(RC2:RC[-1],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-1],0))*1.5"
            ActiveCell(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=INDEX(RC2:RC[-1],MATCH(R6C[-2],R7C2:R7C[-1],0))*1.5"
            ActiveCell(x, 3).FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=INDEX(RC2:RC[-1],MATCH(R6C[-3],R7C2:R7C[-1],0))*1.5"

        ElseIf ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value > 0.1 And ActiveCell(x + 6, 0).Value = 0 And ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value > Cells(5, 6).Value Then
                ActiveCell(x - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=AVERAGE(INDEX(R[1]C2:R[1]C[-2],MATCH(R5C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)):INDEX(R[1],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)))"
                ActiveCell(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=ROUNDUP(((R5C6/R[4]C[-1])/R[2]C[-1])*R[-1]C,2)"
                ActiveCell(x + 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=(R5C6/R[3]C[-1])/R[1]C[-1]"
                ActiveCell(x + 2, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=RC[-1] * R[-1]C * 3"
                ActiveCell(x + 4, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=ROUNDUP(RC[-1] * R[-3]C,2)"
                ActiveCell(x + 5, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=(R[-1]C * R[-3]C) + INDEX(RC2:RC[-2],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0))"
                ActiveCell(x + 6, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=IF(R[-4]C + INDEX(R[-4]C2:R[-4]C[-2],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0))>=2*R[3]C,((R[-4]C+INDEX(R[-4]C2:R[-4]C[-2],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)))/R[3]C)*R4C4,""PAUSE"")"
                ActiveCell(x + 9, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=IF(INDEX(R[-7]C2:R[-7]C[-2],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0))>(R5C6/INDEX(R[-5]C2:R[-5]C[-2],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0))),(R5C6/R[-5]C)*(INDEX(R[-7]C2:R[-7]C[-2],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0))/(R5C6 /INDEX(R[-5]C2:R[-5]C[-2],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)))), R5C6/R[-5]C)"
                ActiveCell(x + 11, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=R[-6]C / R[-5]C"

        ElseIf ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value > 0.1 And ActiveCell(x + 6, 0).Value = 0 And ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value < Cells(5, 6).Value And Cells(5, 6).Value / ActiveCell(x + 4, 0).Value >= 50 Then
                ActiveCell(x - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=AVERAGE(INDEX(R[1]C2:R[1]C[-2],MATCH(R5C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)):INDEX(R[1],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)))"
                ActiveCell(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=ROUNDUP(R[-1]C * 1.1,2)"


        ElseIf ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value > 0.1 And ActiveCell(x + 6, 0).Value = 0 And ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value < Cells(5, 6).Value And Cells(5, 6).Value / ActiveCell(x + 4, 0).Value < 50 Then
                ActiveCell(x - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=AVERAGE(INDEX(R[1]C2:R[1]C[-2],MATCH(R5C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)):INDEX(R[1],MATCH(R6C[-1],R7C2:R7C[-2],0)))"
                ActiveCell(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=ROUNDUP((R5C6 / R[4]C[-1])/50 * R[-1]C,2)"


    Else
        ActiveCell(x, 1).Value = "It Doesn't Work"
        ActiveCell(x, 2).Value = "It Doesn't Work"
        ActiveCell(x, 3).Value = "It Doesn't Work"

        End If
    End If

    If Cells(x, 1).Value = "Sum of Real ACoS" And IsNumeric(ActiveCell(x - 4, 1)) Then
        If ActiveCell(x - 5, 0) > 0 Then

        ActiveCell(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=(INDEX(R[-6]C2:R[-6]C[-1],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-1],0))+(R[-9]C[-1] * R6C * R6C * R[-7]C[-1]) * 3)/((INDEX(R[-5]C2:R[-5]C[-1],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-1],0))/R5C4) +((R[-9]C[-1] * R6C)/R[-2]C[-1]) * R4C4 * 3)"
        ActiveCell(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=(INDEX(R[-6]C2:R[-6]C[-2],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-2],0))+(R[-9]C[-2] * R6C * R6C * R[-7]C[-2]) * 3)/((INDEX(R[-5]C2:R[-5]C[-2],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-2],0))/R5C4) +((R[-9]C[-2] * R6C)/R[-2]C[-2]) * R4C4 * 3)"
        ActiveCell(x, 3).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=(INDEX(R[-6]C2:R[-6]C[-3],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-3],0))+(R[-9]C[-3] * R6C * R6C * R[-7]C[-3]) * 3)/((INDEX(R[-5]C2:R[-5]C[-3],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-3],0))/R5C4) +((R[-9]C[-3] * R6C)/R[-2]C[-3]) * R4C4 * 3)"


        ElseIf ActiveCell(x - 5, 0) = 0 Then

        ActiveCell(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=(INDEX(R[-6]C2:R[-6]C[-1],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-1],0))+(R[-9]C[-1] * R6C * R6C * R[-7]C[-1]) * 3)/((INDEX(R[-5]C2:R[-5]C[-1],MATCH(R1C,R7C2:R7C[-1],0))/R5C4) +((R[-9]C[-1] * R6C)/R[-2]C[-1]) * R4C4 * 3)"


        End If
    End If
Next x

 MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

The third ElseIf statement is the one that needs to be fixed. The line that says
`ActiveCell(x + 5, 0).Value > Cells(5, 6).Value` Needs to instead do a index match function using the date on row 1 current column to look to the left, find the date in row 7 and pull in the number 5 rows lower than the active cell AND THEN see whether it's greater than the value in cell R5C6.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible, or should I try to find another way to solve my issue?